# Versioning using Attribute Routing in ASP .net WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I am trying to implement versioning using AttributeRouting in WEB API. I have defined two folders under Controllers called v1 and v2. I have multiple controllers in each folder. In the Product Controller I define the

RoutePrefix as [RoutePrefix("v1/product")] and [RoutePrefix("v2/product")]

When I go to the URI v1/product it works fine, however v2/product also executes the code in v1 folder. Does attribute routing support versioning or do I have to do something related to Routes as well. My route is defined as

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{namespace}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
```

My product controller looks like

```
namespace API.Controllers
{

[RoutePrefix("v1/product")] 

public class Productv1Controller : ApiController

{

    private DBContext db = new DBContext(); 


    public dynamic Get()
    {
       //Gets the Products
    }
}
```

The code in the V2 product is

```
namespace API.Controllers
{

[RoutePrefix("v2/product")] 

public class Productv2Controller : ApiController

{

    private DBContext db = new DBContext(); 


    public dynamic Get()
    {
       //Gets the Products
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest or provide a link to an example to implement versioning using Attribute Routing

Answer (score 4):

You need to decorate the actions with the Route attribute in order for it to work.

`[Route]
public dynamic Get()
...`

Also, you need to have `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in the WebApiConfig's Register method

**update**

Here's a link to the gist, I tested this in a new web application with WebApi 5 and it worked.
https://gist.github.com/DavidDeSloovere/11367286

Comment: I added the [Route("v1/product")] and [Route("v2/product")] to the GET method but it is still not working. It is always going to the /v1/product irrespective of the path specified in the ROUTE.

Comment: You should not repeat the prefix of the RoutePrefix attribute in the Route attribute. If you want to override the prefix, then you can do something like [Route("~v0/product")]

Comment: Thanks for the gist! I wonder how the number matching in the controller class name works.